# An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeVpcEndpoints operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-emr, amazon-vpc

I am getting this error while executing my lambda

An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the **DescribeVpcEndpoints** operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

My Policy details :

```
Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Sid": "IngestionClusterNodes",
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "s3:*",
                    "glue:*",
                    "kms:*",
                    "sns:*",
                    "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                    "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                    "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
                    "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                    "cloudformation:ListStackResources",
                    "cloudwatch:*",
                    "elasticmapreduce:*",
                    "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                    "secretsmanager:CreateSecret",
                    "secretsmanager:PutResourcePolicy",
                    "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret",
                    "iam:GetGroup",
                    "ec2:*",
                    "events:*",
                    "logs:*",
                    "ses:*",
                    "sns:*",
                    "sns:Publish"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::*",
                    "arn:aws:ses:*",
                    "arn:aws:sqs:*",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::*",
                    "arn:aws:logs:*",
                    "arn:aws:sns:*",
                    "arn:aws:cloudformation:*",
                    "arn:aws:cloudwatch:*",
                    "arn:aws:secretsmanager:*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:*",
                    "arn:aws:events:*:*:*",
                    "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
                    "arn:aws:autoscaling:*"
                  ]
                }
```

I have attached above policy to Lambda execution role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you simply modify your statement to;

```
            {
              "Sid": "IngestionClusterNodes",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "glue:*",
                "kms:*",
                "sns:*",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:ListStackResources",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "elasticmapreduce:*",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "secretsmanager:CreateSecret",
                "secretsmanager:PutResourcePolicy",
                "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret",
                "iam:GetGroup",
                "ec2:*",
                "events:*",
                "logs:*",
                "ses:*",
                "sns:*",
                "sns:Publish"
              ],
              "Resource": ["*"]
            }
```

Just a note, VPCendpoint don't have Arns. Only id, vpce-092e602ea1a16886e so your ec2:* in resource block didn't allow you to describe vpc endpoints.

Comment: This stuff is so frustrating. How are we supposed to know or determine things like "VPCendpoint doesn't have Arns"? And when we put those "*" Resource values how do we know this is correct when we're supposed to be implementing 'least privileges' for security? Ugh.